# LaravelShoppingcart not work in laravel6.2.0

Tags: php, laravel

I want to install a shopping cart i am using laravel 6.2.0 now

`$ composer require gloudemans/shoppingcart`

can anybody advise me to solve it?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: that package doesn't support Laravel 6.x ... they would need to update the composer requirements for that package

Comment: Looks like that package only supports Laravel up to 5.7. Go find a different package

Comment: now i can solve it

Answer (score 0):

use this link
https://github.com/bumbummen99/LaravelShoppingcart

```
composer require bumbummen99/shoppingcart
```

this will help.

Comment: Help with what? Definitely will  not help with installing gloudemans/shoppingcart

Comment: i think gloudemans/shoppingcart is abandoned, try alternatives like bumbummn99, darryldecode, hardevine